# Strange behaviour of an IF condition

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$a = 101;

if (isset($a) && is_int($a) && in_array($a, range(1, 100))) {
  echo "TRUE";
} else echo "FALSE";
```

Why this condition returns FALSE as it should be while this IF:

```
if (isset($argv[1]) && is_int($argv[1]) && in_array($argv[1], range(1, 100))) {
  echo "TRUE";
} else echo "FALSE";
```

returns also FALSE where value passed as first parameter is 50 which is in range??? PHP-CLI is 7.0.9-TS-VC14-x64

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe that parameter has the value `"50"`, so is of type _string_?

Comment: Or maybe you actually want to use `$argv[0]` instead, since you refer to it as _first_ argument?

Comment: What does the `$argv` contain?

Comment: Apply (int) before $argv[1]  everywhere in condition and check. (type casting)

Comment: No, no and no
`$argv[0]` is the script name, I'm passing 50 (no quotes) to `$argv[1]`
This is a simple check and it worked 40-50 minutes ago. No changes were done on the script and just stopped ...

Comment: @Anant Why should I cast it when the goal is to check against non-int values?

Comment: @1000Gbps  then  range(1, 100)  and  is_int($argv[1])  is unnecessary in your condition

Comment: Yep, you're right. Changed `is_int` to `is_numeric()` and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[1]` is, by default, an string. 
Use [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instead of is_int(), and convert (or cast) it to integer value before checking if in the range.

```
// var_dump($argv); // ...if you want to check $argv types and values.
if (isset($argv[1]) && is_numeric($argv[1]) && in_array(intval($argv[1]), range(1, 100))) {
  echo "TRUE";
} 
else {
  echo "FALSE";
}
```

***CAUTION***: is_numeric() also returns TRUE in case of a float value!

Comment: Noticed that. Seems `range()` automatically converts the type of the needle, so `intval()` is not necessary

Comment: Then your issue was only due to the use if is_int(), which doesn't check if the values is a numeric string. is_numeric() does the job. But, CAUTION: is_numeric() also returns TRUE in case of a float value! Not sure is this might affect you in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird why `range()` do not check FLOATs

Comment: That's the reason of using intval() in the in_array($x, range(...)): in case your input is a float value (i.e. "25.5") it will convert it to it's integer part (25), which will be in the range(1, 100) generated array (step 1 by default).